# split string and leave the separators intact

Tags: javascript

I cannot find a good way to split a string using a separator string but leave the separator as the prefix of each element of the resulting array:

from

```
var s = 'blah0__blah1__blah2';
```

I need to get

```
['blah0', '__blah1', '__blah2']
```

the closest thing that I could get was

```
s.split(/(__)/);
```

which returns

```
['blah0', '__', 'blah1', '__', 'blah2']
```

but this I would need to traverse to merge the underscores.

Is there a better way?

EDIT:

here is my best effort so far:

```
'blah__blah1__blah2'.split(/(__[^_]+)/)
// => ["blah", "__blah1", "", "__blah2", ""]
```

still, there are empty strings in the output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
var s = 'blah0__blah__blah'
var s_split = s.match(/(__)?(.(?!__))+./g)
console.log(s_split)
```

I'm pretty sure it's much more costly (time and memory wise) than simply reiterating and joining after a regular `split`.

If you replace `__` with your separator it should work fine for most cases.

Comment: thanks. looks like using a string instead of a regex as a separator is faster. even though I will have to iterate over the resulting array again.

Answer (score 1):

A two-step process.

```
var s = 'blah0__blah1__blah2';
var blahs = s.split('__');
var scoreBlahs = blahs.map(preScore);
alert(scoreBlahs);
function preScore(b) {
    var x;
    var result = x.concat('__',b);  
    return result; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'blah0__blah1__blah2'.match(/^[^_]+|_+[^_]+/g);
["blah0", "__blah1", "__blah2"]
```

Seems to give you what you want. Though It may vary, if your input isn't exactly as you show it.

Comment: @wroniasty I've changed it to account for any length (this would be `1..infinity` potentially), but if you know the range beforehand, you can change `+` after the `_` to be that range, as in, for example: `_{2,42}`.

Answer (score 0):

Just prepend the seperator after you seperate the string

```
var value = "a,b,c";
var splitter = value.split(",");
for(var i = 0; i < splitter.length; i++) {
    alert("," + splitter[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the separator - just add it again later on:

```
var s = 'blah0__blah1__blah2';
var sep = '__';
var arr = s.split(sep);
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = sep + arr[i];
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: He already told to get better solution than traversing and prepending the seprator.

Comment: Somewhat true, however in my solution you only need to modify the array values, which is more efficient than *merging* the values of siblings in the array, and then modifying the array (with e.g. `slice`).

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a secondary separator, and split on that, leaving the original intact.

```
var s = 'blah0__blah1__blah2';
s = s.replace('_', '_$');
s.split('$');
```